# Detecting mouse click on specific SKPath using skiasharp SKControl

Tags: winforms, skiasharp

I am using the Skiasharp Windows Forms SKControl to handle drawing actions within my app. Part of the functionality is to be able to click on the canvas to select a specific "layer" and allow the user to apply a different color to each layer. See the image below for an example.

[image: three layered image]

The three layers in this image are drawn as three separate paths. For the most part, the code that I have is working great, except for when those "layers" overlap. If I click on the lightest layer in the above image at a point that is lower than the "point" of the darkest layer, it will select the darker layer.

This makes sense since I am using `path.GetBounds()` which returns an SKRect. On mouse click I am creating an SKRect from the click location and then calling `rect.IntersectsWith(mouseRect)` to determine which "layer" I clicked on.

**How can I validate layer clicked given the paths are not simple rectangles?**

Here is the code that I am using for the "HitTest" (non-optimized since I was debugging)

```
            SKRect hitRect = SKRect.Create(scaledPixelPosition, new SKSize(20f, 20f));
            ElementLayerInfo elementLayerInfo = new ElementLayerInfo();

            foreach(Element element in _elements)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ElementLayerInfo>  kvp in element.ElementLayers)
                {
                    if (kvp.Value.LayerRect.IntersectsWith(hitRect))
                    {
                        elementLayerInfo = kvp.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: In this case, if you get more than one layerrect intersection. You need to check the exact mouseclick position on your polygone within your SkPath, by getting alle the points with `GetPoints()`.

Comment: https://wrfranklin.org/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html